# Сохранение данных в хранилище телефона по типу shared preferences

Tags: android, kotlin

Изучаю Android и заинтересовал вопрос: как сохранить несколько пар Int данных в Kotlin при перезагрузке приложения, данные по типу количество правильных ответов категории квиза/всего ответов. В голову пришли только shared preferences и Room, но есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Новая библиотека от Google - [DataStore](https://habr.com/ru/company/tinkoff/blog/525010/), есть еще либы попроще Room, как Paper - https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

Comment: Для "несколько пар Int данных" shared preferences вполне достаточно. Либо просто в файл сохраните. Не смыла тянуть зависимости из-за десятка байт неструктурированных данных.